# Gridview edit, click twice problem

Tags: asp.net

I am using a GridView and I encountered the click twice on the Edit link to see the edit fields problem. Following advice I am binding my GridView again on the .RowEditing handler. The problem persist that I only see edit fields after my second click on any of the Edit links.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="GridViewTest._Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <h2>
            Welcome to ASP.NET!
        </h2>
        <p>
            To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
            <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c1" HeaderText="C1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c2" HeaderText="C2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c3" HeaderText="C3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c4" HeaderText="C4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c5" HeaderText="C5" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c6" HeaderText="C6" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c7" HeaderText="C7" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c8" HeaderText="C8" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </p>
        <p>
            You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
                title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
        </p>
    </asp:Content>





    Public Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                loaddata()
            End If
        End Sub

        Sub loaddata()

        'Get dataview dvAgTarRet_gv



            gvReport.DataSource = dvAgTarRet_gv
                    gvReport.DataBind()
            Session.Add("gvReport", dvAgTarRet_gv)

            end sub
```

Comment: You need to post up your code behind to demonstrate how you are databinding. It sounds like you are inappropriately binding the data to the gridview and loosing the viewstate, therefore the event cannot be associated with the original control state. Try only binding if the page is not in postback mode using Page.Postback.

Comment: Brian, ok I now have a empty .RowEditing handler. And after the clicking on edit that cause the postback I dont see any textboxes/change to the page?

Comment: fran, you need to post your code / markup up to review.

Comment: Code added. @Brian Scott

Answer (score 22):

Found it. Needed to set the gridview's EditIndex and then do a databind.

```
Private Sub gvReport_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvReport.RowEditing
    gvReport.DataSource = CType(Session("gvReport"), DataView)
    gvReport.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    gvReport.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Of the 100 "solutions" to this problem I've read, this is the one that works. Thanks fran.

Comment: +1 Surely worked to add the specific data binding method as per one's code.

Answer (score 5):

Just call your grid binding function:

```
protected void GvEmployee_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GvEmployee.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindgridview();  // method of binding gridview
}
```