# Click edit button twice in gridview asp.net c# issue

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a gridview created on a page where I want to provide an edit button for the user to click in. However the issue is the grid view row becomes editable only while clicking the edit button second time. Not sure what is going wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

One additional point is my grid view is displayed on the page only on a click of a button and is not there on page_load event hence.

Posting the code snippets:

//MY Aspx code

```
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slice" SortExpression="name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblslice" Text='<%# Eval("slice") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblslice" Text='<%# Eval("slice") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Metric" SortExpression="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblmetric" Text='<%# Eval("metric")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblmetric" Text='<%# Eval("metric")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Original" SortExpression="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbloriginal" Text='<%# Eval("Original")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbloriginal" Text='<%# Eval("Original")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WOW" SortExpression="Market">
                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblwow" Text='<%# Eval("WOW")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblwow" Text='<%# Eval("WOW")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change" SortExpression="Market" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblChange" Text='<%# Eval("Change")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCustomerID" Text='<%# Eval("Change") %> ' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

//My code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



}

public void populagridview1(string slice,string fromdate,string todate,string year)
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_geteventchanges";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@slice", slice);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@fromdate", fromdate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@todate", todate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@year", year);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}

protected void ImpactCalc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populagridview1(ddl_slice.SelectedValue, dt_to_integer(Picker1.Text),        dt_to_integer(Picker2.Text), Txt_Year.Text);

}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{


    gvEditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    Gridview1.DataBind();


}
```

[My page layout](http://i44.tinypic.com/35n4myr.png)

This edit screen appears after clicking edit twice.. the grid view gets displayed on hitting the Calculate impact button. The data is from a backend stored procedure which is fired on clicking the Calculate impact button

Comment: You need to provide more details than this. Show the markup for the entire grid, and also show how you're binding the grid in the code-behind (when and where `populategridview1` gets called).

Comment: After clicking the edit button does the page have to reload the dynamic grid view? If so how do you know to create the dynamic grid view in this case?

Comment: This question is already responsed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433776/gridview-edit-click-twice-problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `bind gridview` again in edit function `GridView1_RowEditing` 
You need to modify your code as follows

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvEditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //call the function here
    populagridview1(ddl_slice.SelectedValue, dt_to_integer(Picker1.Text), 
                                    dt_to_integer(Picker2.Text), Txt_Year.Text);
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Binding Data in Label use **Bind Method** instead of **Eval Method**.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't give you a whole answer, but I think this may point you in the right direction. Usually, when I see something like this, it has to do with the [Page Lifecycle](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx). Take a good look at the order in which your events are firing. It may be that your edit button only works on the second try due to the timing of the data binding relative to the event firing.

Comment: Post a comment asking for more details instead of posting a generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slice" SortExpression="name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblslice" Text='<%# Eval("slice") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblslice" Text='<%# Eval("slice") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>//in this place give textbox control
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

in edititemtemplate, you are giving label instead of textbox. So please change label to textbox in edititemtemplate and see it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your event

```
 protected void grdViewDetails_RowEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs e) {
  grdViewDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  Page_Load(null, null);
 }
```

That Page_Load(null,null) -Postback- loads your datagridview with the new EditIndex (Given you update your gridview on the page_load event)

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I found same problem. What I did to fix it was add `Gridview1.DataBind()` outside `if(!IsPostBack)` and in each event handler.

Comment: You seem to be missing the rest of your sentence!

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `!Page.IsPostBack` condition in your page load.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment. OP needs to provide more details, otherwise we're just guessing.